# Linq query between two list objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects:

```
ObjectA
{
   string code;
   string country;
}

ObjectB
{
   string code;
   string otherstuff;
}
```

And I have `List<objectA>` and `List<ObjectB>` and I need to find all objects in `List<ObjectB>` which contains `objectA.Code`.
But cannot manage to implement it on LINQ query.

Comment: 1. Do you have single `objectA` or you need it for all objects from `List<objectA>`. 2. What is the layout of result you expect? 3. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have also a look at IEnumerable.Intersect: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in both and allow to compare with each other via `Code`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to find all instances of `ObjectB` which have a `code` value present in any of the `List<ObjectA>` values.  If so try the following

```
List<ObjectA> listA = ...;
List<ObjectB> listB = ...;
var all = listB.Where(b => listA.Any(a => a.code == b.code));
```

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you want to join the list of ObjectA with the list of ObjectB on the `code` property. This is one way:

```
List<ObjectA> listOfA = ...;
List<ObjectB> listOfB = ...;
var all = from a in listOfA
          join b in listOfB on a.code equals b.code
          select new {a,b};
```

The result is a list of anonymous objects, containing 2 properties: a of type ObjectA, b of type ObjectB, with the same `code`

Answer (score 6):

To do this effectively you can first put the codes into a `HashSet<string>` and then use a `Contains()` query to check if the B in question has a code that is contained in the hashset:

```
var codes = new HashSet<string>(listOfAs.Select(x => x.code));
var selectedBs = listOfBs.Where( x=> codes.Contains(x.code));
```

Answer (score 5):

I would put the codes of the `ObjectA` list into a HashSet, otherwise your query would become an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation. Like this it is an O(n) operation:

```
var aList = new List<ObjectA>();
var bList = new List<ObjectB>();

var aCodes = new HashSet<string>(aList.Select(a => a.code));
var result = bList.Where(b => aCodes.Contains(b.code));
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. Do you know any nice tutorials in linq or books with examples in speed and etc?

Comment: For LINQ Google [LINQ tutorial C#](http://www.google.com/search?q=LINQ+tutorial+C%23). As for speed, what is relevant here, is to have a basic knowledge of the different collection types along with their pros and cons. James Michael Hare gives a good overview here: [Choosing the Right Collection Class](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)